# Empty panda dataframe when working with excel with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, pandas

I am working with a directory of excel sheets and have decided to use Panda Dataframes to deal with it. As an example I have an excel spread sheet of the form:
[image: Excel sheet I want to parse]

Each excel file has multiple sheets. Also, they contain merged cells. To tackle this I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

files=os.listdir(path)
files_xl=[file for file in files if file[-4:]=='xlsx']

df=pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xl:
    try:
        data=pd.ExcelFile(path+f)
        xl=[data.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in data.sheet_names]
        for item in xl:
            item.index=pd.Series(item.index).fillna(method='ffill')
            df.append(item)
    except:
        continue
```

However, it (1) returns an empty dataframe and (2)does not replace the NaNs which result from the merged cells.

Comment: have you not tried `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: thanks, so I tried `data=pd.read_excel(path+f)
data.index=pd.Series(data.index).fillna(method='ffill')
df=df.append(data)` and this solved the empty dataframe problem, but I still have NaNs appearing as well as it only seems to be reading the 1st sheet in the file.

Comment: read the docs for `read_excel`. it tells you things you need to know. as for the `nan`s, that makes sense if they're at the the top of the df because, well, your replacement message is forward fill.